# compare columns from file1 and extracting patterns from file 2 in unix

Tags: unix, grep, compare

```
File 1 contains   
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
0,0,0,1,2
file 2 contains 
12,12,11,a,b,c,d,e,f,22,33,22
11,22,22,1,2,3,4,5,33,22,33,ww
```

I would like if the patterns from file 1 is found in file 2 then the entire line from file 2 be printed. 
So far i have tried

```
grep -f file 1 file 2
grep -F
```

but they does not seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -Ff file1 file2
12,12,11,a,b,c,d,e,f,22,33,22
11,22,22,1,2,3,4,5,33,22,33,ww
```

Because your patterns appear to be fixed strings, not regular expressions, I added the `-F` flag.

Comment: i have tried the different variations of grep -f, -Ff, fgrep but i get that its an illegal operation or i'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: @jojo Please show the _exact_ error message that you get.  Also, what OS?

Comment: grep: illegal option -- F
grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10

Comment: @jojo OK. SunOS tools are notoriously buggy.  Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep  -Ff file1 file2` If that doesn't work, try  `/usr/xpg6/bin/grep  -Ff file1 file2`